# Error using the library Modelica_LinearSystems2 in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to use the Kalman Filter from the Modelica_LinearSystem2 Library (Modelica_LinearSystems2.WorkInProgress.Controller.KalmanFilter.KF) in OpenModelica, but it seems the functions of the library are not working properly in my test models.

To find the problem I copied the code example from the documentation (https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace.%27constructor%27.fromABCDMatrices.html)

```
model test3

  Real A[1,1] = [1];
  Real B[1,1] = [1];
  Real C[1,1] = [1];
  Real D[1,1] = [0];

public
  Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace ss;

algorithm
  ss := Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace.'constructor'.fromABCDMatrices(A, B, C, D);


equation

end test3;
```

When I click on **check model** I receive the Error:

> [Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace: 7:3-8:68]: Failed to deduce dimension 1 of A due to missing binding equation.

This refers to the line

```
Real A[:,size(A, 1)];
```

When I predefine this (and other) matrices with for example

```
Real A[4,4];
```

I get the error

> Internal error Instantiation of test3 failed with no error message.

My question is: Why is this and how can I prevent these errors?

Answer (score 2):

### Findings

It looks like Modelica_LinearSystems2 is only supported by Dymola. The landing page of their [github repository](https://github.com/modelica/Modelica_LinearSystems2) states:

> Please note that the library is known to work with Dymola only.

It looks as this is still the case. At least on my machine the library Modelica_LinearSystems2 v2.4.1 has serious issues in OpenModelica v1.18.0. Most examples exit with errors or do nothing.

Still, the code in the question does not work in Dymola. Below you find an explanation and corrected examples, which were successfully tested with Dymola. The fundamental problem should be the same in all tools and I hope my solution will also work in OpenModelica once it support the Modelica_LinearSystems2 library.

### Original answer (most relevant for Dymola users)

The problem with your example code is that Modelica tools must know the size of vectors, matrices and arrays when a *simulation* is performed, but not when a function is called. Since you are building a model, the tool assumes that you want to *simulate* it.

Your code instantiates the `StateSpace` record `ss`. `ss` holds the matrices `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. As long as you don't assign anything to `ss`, their sizes are not known. Of course there is an algorithm, which sets `ss`, but this happens during simulation. During translation, the size of the matrices in `ss` cannot be determined. Therefore, a typical Modelica tool requires you to use a binding equation.

To make your snipped work, you can change it to this:

```
model Demo
  Real A[1,1] = [1];
  Real B[1,1] = [1];
  Real C[1,1] = [1];
  Real D[1,1] = [0];
  Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace ss = Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace.'constructor'.fromABCDMatrices(A, B, C, D);
end Demo;
```

Note that `ss` now has a binding equation. Hence, the size of the matrices inside `ss` can be determined.

The question is, if you really want to run a simulation with your `StateSpace` record. Typically, the functions in the liner systems library are used in Modelica functions. In this case your code could look as follows:

```
function demo
  output Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace ss;
protected
  Real A[1,1] = [1];
  Real B[1,1] = [1];
  Real C[1,1] = [1];
  Real D[1,1] = [0];
algorithm
  ss = Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace.'constructor'.fromABCDMatrices(A, B, C, D);
end demo;
```

I suggest looking at the various examples in the package `Modelica_LinearSystems2.Examples.StateSpace` for the correct usage of the `StateSpace` record.

Comment: There is an issue on M_LS2 github regarding using standard Modelica: https://github.com/modelica/Modelica_LinearSystems2/issues/131

Comment: I saw the note on github so I downloaded Modelica_LinearSystems2_v2.4.0. When I change my test model to yours, I still receive the missing binding equation error :(